# What is the normal approximation of binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus

I can't find a specific formula for this problem where I have to use the normal approximation of the binomial distribution.

Suppose we have a Bernoulli experiment with $p=0.8$ and we want to know how many trials we need for $\mathbb{P}(X\ge 30)$ to get the probability $0.975$

So what we have is

$n$ = unknown

$p$ = 0.8

$q$ = 0.2

$\mathbb{P}(X\ge 30)$

$0.975$

I have to use the normal approximation of the binomial distribution to solve this problem but I can't find any formula for this.

The only thing I found is $$Z=\frac{Y-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\rightarrow N(0,1)$$

Will be this the approximation formula?

Answer (score 2):

For large $n$ and/or $p$ close to $1/2$, the $\text{Bin}(n,p)$ distribution looks roughly like a normal distribution with the same mean and standard deviation. Since the mean of a $\text{Bin}(n,p)$ random variable is $np$ and the standard deviation is $\sqrt{np(1-p)}$, this means we can approximate a $\text{Bin}(n,p)$ random variable by a $N(np,np(1-p))$ random variable.

To actually do that approximation, we have to be a little careful because binomial random variables take on whole number quantities, but normal random variables take on real values. If $X \sim \text{Bin}(n,p)$ and $Y\sim N(np, np(1-p))$, then for any whole number $k$,
$$P(X=k) \approx P\left(k-\frac{1}{2} \leq Y \leq k+\frac{1}{2}\right).$$
That is, to account for the fact that $Y$ does not always take on whole number values, we consider every value of $Y$ in the interval $\left[k-\frac{1}{2},k+\frac{1}{2}\right]$ to be roughly $k$. Similarly, if we have integers $k<\ell$, then 
\begin{align*}
P(k \leq X \leq \ell) &\approx P\left(k-\frac{1}{2} \leq Y \leq \ell+\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
P(X \leq \ell) &\approx P\left(Y \leq \ell+\frac{1}{2}\right)\\
P(k \leq X) &\approx P\left(k-\frac{1}{2} \leq Y\right).
\end{align*}
All of the probabilities on the right-hand side can be found by computing the $z$-scores (with $\mu=np$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{np(1-p)}$) and using a $z$-chart.

For your problem, $n$ is unknown, so we have to work backward. We want
\begin{align*}
0.975 &= P(X \geq 30) \\
&\approx P(Y \geq 29.5) \\
&= P\left( Z \geq \frac{29.5-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\right) \\
&= 1-P\left( Z \leq \frac{29.5-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\right) 
\end{align*}
where $Y \sim N(np,np(1-p))$ and $Z\sim N(0,1)$. Now you can use a $z$-chart to find the value of $\frac{29.5-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}$, plug in the value of $p$, and solve for $n$. If $n$ turns out not to be in integer, then you need to figure out whether it should be rounded up or down. (Hint: you want $P(X \geq 30)$ to be *at least* $0.975$. Does this probability get bigger or smaller as $n$ increases?)

Comment: Thank you this helped me a lot. That means I have to solve $0.975=1-P\left(Z \le \frac{29.5-0.8n}{\sqrt{(0.16n))}}\right)$

Comment: but what will be my $Z$ ?

Comment: As I said in my answer, $Z$ is a $N(0,1)$ random variable, i.e., a normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $1$. Are you familiar with $z$-charts like this: http://sixsigmastudyguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/z-table.jpg? You should find the entry in the chart that is closest to $0.975$ and use that to obtain the $z$-value. This will be the value of $\frac{29.5-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}$.

Comment: It's been a while since I used z charts. Last time was in school and now in University we have probability theory and we recently started normal distribution. I looked at the table which you provided me in the link and the closest z value to $0.975$ is in line $1.9$ and row $0.06$ with the z value $0.9750$

Comment: $0.975$ is not the $z$-score, rather it is the probability that a $N(0,1)$ random variable is less than or equal to the $z$-score. You said it is in row $1.9$ and column $0.06$, which means the $z$-score is $1.96$.

Comment: So then we have $1.96 \le \frac{29.5-0.8n}{0.4n}$ with $n \approx18.62$

Comment: But 19 seems to be an unrealistic solution

Comment: Oh, I missed this - since we want $0.975= 1-P\left(Z-\frac{29.5-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}\right)$, you should be looking up $1-0.975$ in the $z$-chart. In any case, you also made a mistake in solving for $n$ - the denominator should be $0.4\sqrt{n}$ not $0.4n$.

Comment: Alright thank you for your support. According to Wolfram Alpha the solution is $34.570 \approx 35$

Comment: No, $35$ is not correct, see my most recent comment about which probability to look up in the $z$-chart.

Comment: Careful - the row is $-1.9$ and the column is $0.06$ so it should be $z= -1.96$. The row tells you the ones place and tenths place of the $z$-score, and the column tells you the hundreds place.

Comment: Alright I looked in the table again we got $-1.9-0.6=-1.96$ then we have $-1.96= \frac{29.5-0.8n}{0.4 \sqrt{n}}$ solving for n is $n \approx 39 $

Comment: The equation $-1.96 = \frac{29.5-0.8n}{0.4\sqrt{n}}$ is correct, but $n \approx 39$ is not.

Comment: According to Wolfram Alpha the solution is $n \approx 43.326$

Comment: Yes, I agree with that.